# What is $P(B)$ given $P(D), P(C), P(C|D), P(B|C), P(B|D), P(B|CD), P(B|C^cD^c)$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Given the known values,
$$P(CD) = P(C|D)P(D)$$$$P(C^cD) = P(C^c|D)P(D) = (1 - P(C|D))P(D)$$

Then using these values we find,

$$P(D|C) = \frac{P(CD)}{P(C)}, \, P(D|C^c) = \frac{P(C^cD)}{P(C^c)}$$

This gives us $P(D^c|C)$ and $P(D^c|C^c)$. Using these values

$$ P(CD^c) = P(D^c|C)P(C)$$$$P(C^cD^c) = (D^c|C^c)P(C^c)$$

Now to calculate $P(B)$ we get this long expression,

$$P(B) = P(B|DC)P(DC) + P(B|D^cC)P(D^cC) + P(B|DC^c)P(DC^c) + P(B|D^cC^c)P(D^cC^c)$$

I do not know how to calculate $P(B|D^cC)$ and $P(B|DC^c)$ from here. Is this the wrong way to calculate $P(B)$?

Comment: That formula for computing P(B) is not wrong, but we have no way from the info you are sharing with us, to tell you if there is any better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that
$$
\Pr(B \cap D^c \cap C) + \Pr(B \cap D \cap C) =  \Pr(B \cap C)
$$
You know the second and third term, so you can find the first one.

You can find $\Pr(B \cap D \cap C^c)$ in a similar way.